# Wordpress Meta Field - Finding the values of a select meta- field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have created a custom field ( a select box) for certain post type - flavors. the custom field type can have flavors like vanilla, chocolate etc.. which will be set at run-time by administrators.

I have requirement, where I need to list the values at run time that has been set for the custom field type choices.

How do I do this?

get_post_meta will only return the value set for a particular post id.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement right (and tbh I'm not sure), following code should do what you need.

```
global $wpdb;
$flavors=$wpdb->get_col('SELECT `meta_value` from `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta` WHERE `meta_key`=\'flavor\' GROUP BY `meta_value`;');
if (count($flavors) > 0)
{
    foreach ($flavors as $flavor)
    {
    //do whatever you need with $flavor (meta_value)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, @Igor - my question was not clear enough . So I have a custom post type called Ice-Cream - it has a custom field called Flavors - now to make the life of backend-editors easier, Flavors is actually a select box (single select combo-box) prepopulated with values like "vanilla", "chocolate", "mango". I have to write code to figure out what are the prepopulated value of Flavors.. what are the possible choices that Flavors can have..?

Comment: @AsifM do you have code for this select one? You could figure where it gets its values from. The code above gets all unique values of `flavors` field present in the database (in other words, which were added to at least post)

Comment: the content editors for the website will add values for "flavors" at runtime - so they will essentially login to the backend and use a "Advanced Field Configuration" plugin to add and remove values (vanilla, chocolate) to the custom field flavor. then they will modify each post and associate one value of flavor (e.g. vanilla) to that post. I have no means of knowing the values that "flavors" can have before hand in code.

Comment: I am not looking to get the "flavor" value assigned to one particular post - I am more specifically looking to see what are the possible values "flavor" can have

Comment: @AsifM the code above would not get it for one particular post, it'd get all values assigned and present in database. But I guess this is bit different from what you want. You just gotta look through code of this plugin  and find where it stores what your editors put in the configuration. Most likely though, it's somewhere in options table. Can you share a link to this plugin?

Comment: This is what I am looking for "http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field_object/" but I was looking for a wordpressy code instead of having to call the plugins API.. is that possible?

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. Appreciate you trying to help me out